# Paypal NVP Api set order status "completed"

Tags: curl, paypal

I am using the old NVP REST API via php with methodes "DoExpressCheckoutPayment"
A simple curl is created, a transactionID returned

Can someone tell me how I can set a order status to "confirmed"?
What method and parameters are used? for digital products (so no tracking info)

It just happens that paypal sometimes set a transaction on HOLD until I set it manual to confirmed, whats a lot of work.

How would a curl look like to confirm a transaction order status? What **METHODE?**

This is what I use at the moment:

```
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t".$paypalmode.".paypal.com/nvp";
        $version = urlencode('76.0');

        // Set the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
        $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

        // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

        // Get response from the server.
        $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

The API call `METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment` executes an Express Checkout transaction. The resulting status can be `PENDING`, which depending on the `PENDINGREASON` may require manual action in the https://www.paypal.com account .

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I have been asking for.

Comment: Not the "payment" from the customer is pending.

Comment: Paypal sets the amount on HOLD for some days, until I confirm the "shipping state" to be "send" or "oder status" "complete"

What I need is to click trough paypal, select payment, click on "receive money", click on change order status, click on "digital goods", click on "completed", click on "no date needed"...6-7 clicks.

I want to add "tracking information" to the received payment, so paypal is happy and knows the goods are send out. but there is no carrier, so tracking = digital ...status = complete...methode ???

Comment: If no shipping is needed, you can set `NOSHIPPING=1` in the SetExpressCheckout API call.

Comment: the NOSHIPPING=1 does not change the behaviour. Also a digital product has to be "confirmed" as beeing processed.

Comment: noshipping just means, that paypal does NOT ask the customer for an adresse and will NOT forward the address.

Comment: still they want a confirmation and then ask if it is goods or digital product..

Comment: It means there will be no shipping as part of the paypal transaction, is what it means.  It is possible to pass line item variables with an item category, `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMCATEGORYm`, etcetera. I'm not aware of this being helpful, but you could try it. For the most part the behavior you describe is not a standard one and maybe particular to your account or region. You should ask PayPal about it.